# How to navigate another page in native-script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, native, nativescript-vue

I am trying to create a simple button on native script called 'login'. I have created a login component but when I test the code it says no known component for element Login.

```
<template>
<Page>
    <TabView height="100%" />
    <ActionBar title="Home" />
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <!--Add your page content here-->
            <Label textWrap="true" text="Play with NativeScript!"
                class="h2 description-label" />
            <Button text="Login" @tap="onLoginTap" />
            <Login>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </TabView>
</Page>
</template>

<script>
import Login from "./login";
export default {
    data() {
        return {};
    };
},
methods: {
    onLoginTap: function() {
        this.$navigateTo(Login);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks scattered, methods are written outside exports / I'm not usre why you have self closing TabView and another closing tag hanging alone at bottom of template. Please share a complete & neat code, possibly a Playground sample.

Comment: Please could you have a look at the code here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=CxNnsM&v=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various issues in your code

- You can only navigate between Page, your login component was not wrapped by Page element
- I'm not sure why you are using TabView, it's used only when you have tabbed application and there is a specific component hierarchy. Refer documentation for more details. I have removed it as it doesn't seem required for your Page
- You are not suppose to embed Login as a tag in the same Page

Overall I would suggest you to go through the basics of docs to avoid such issues.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=CxNnsM&v=8)

Comment: v-template is meant to be used with ListView. As I already said, do not use something randomly. Try to understand the meaning of element before using it.

Comment: I was initially using list-view but then got rid of it and forget to get rid of v-template. But is that why my button is not working?

Comment: I have mentioned the same so many times now, please focus on the documentation, do not presume the attributes / things exists. It's not v-for with ListView, it's just for. It do not need or have a key attribute. Also `filteredClassses` computed function is broken, make sure the object is valid before accessing it.

Comment: No it's not nativescript issue, it's your code. That far I can say, also your API end point is always invalid when I checked. So I can not comment much there.

Comment: Check the length of filteredClasses, it's always 0.